# How can I connect to Twitter API via a proxy?

Tags: twitter, twitter-api

I am a starter and need to connect to Twitter API via a proxy and tweet : Hello World?

My web site is .NET, C# and I want to tweet events on my site to Twitter via Twitter API.

Please give me an easy, summarized instruction note to do that.

Comment: Sorry but API questions are off topic for [webapps.se] - [Are API questions on topic or off topic?](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/q/740)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the sample code. http://psantos-blog.zi-yu.com/?p=197

Basically you need use `request.Proxy = new WebProxy("http://localhost:8080", false);` this code to specify the proxy.